# is it possible to fetch multiple aws s3 object head (metadata)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm using AWS S3 to store my end-users' files in a single Bucket. My backend is in Golang.

In my web interface, I want any user in its personal space to be able to see its files and folders names, MIME type, size and last modified date. To achieve this I saw:

```golang
func (c *S3) HeadObject(input *HeadObjectInput) (*HeadObjectOutput, error)
```

It's nice if I want to get a single file metadata but I can't find an equivalent for multiple files.

Something of the kind of `ListObjectsV2` where I can use prefixes and delimiters to narrow the search but without the full content of the files would be perfect.

If there isn't an endpoint to fetch multiple files metadata, what could be the best approach ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't think anything like that exists. Even AWS itself uses a dynamo+s3 combo in cases where they need quick + fancy metadata queries.

Comment: I am surprised, I really thought this could be common usecase. But anyway thank you ! Using a combo between a db and s3 could be cool, do you have any resource on that ? So I can learn if it's worth the pain of doing it

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html - basically, every object modification on s3 can emit an event to Lambda. Lambda handler can update the db.

Comment: oh thanks really, I understand better how to proceed. Your input should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following list of system-defined metadata you could get from S3.

1. List item
2. Content-Length
3. Last-Modified
4. Content-Type
5. Content-MD5
6. x-amz-server-side-encryption
7. x-amz-version-id
8. x-amz-delete-marker
9. x-amz-storage-class
10. x-amz-website-redirect-location
11. x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id
12. x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm

if you're looking for is headObject(metadata) the HEAD operation retrieves metadata from an object without returning the object itself. This operation is useful if you're only interested in an object's metadata.

please refer below [Document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#headobject)

edit: some sample code from aws doc

[image]